# How to record photo/video files smaller on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, video

My iPhone photos and videos are too high resolution so that I can't send them via email or facebook messenger.

I rarely need high-definition photo and video, and I'd like to set the default resolution much lower than it is out of the box.

Is this possible? And is it possible to shrink the file size of my existing large photos and videos?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you describe. When sending an email, you can't select more than 5 photos at once, but there are workarounds. When sending, you're asked for the size of the pictures (S, M, L, Actual Size). If you're talking about the email server refusing to send your pictures or videos, the problem may lie on the message size limitations on your server. When attaching an image or video to Facebook Messenger there's no warning whatsoever. Could you please add screenshots of the problems or error messages you've encountered?

Comment: I'm wondering if these are longer videos that you are trying to share? What is the average length of the video in question?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Video Slimmer app in app store.. This app lets you to shrink video files filmed on your iOS device to smaller file size while keeping good video quality. With just several taps, you will greatly save the precious space on iPhone iPad or iPod.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 9, one can go to Settings > Photos & Camera and select Record Video or Record Slo-Mo to change the resolution of the videos being recorded, thus making them take up less space.